# Sync Sqlite data with Amazon Cognito

Tags: javascript, cordova, amazon-web-services, ionic-framework

I have a mobile app developed with Javascript (Ionic). I have stored the data locally on Sqlite. Now I wish to sync data with Amazon Cognito whenever the internet connection is available. Cognito provides an API for Javascript but it I would need to replace all Sqlite implementation with Cognito.

Here's what I am looking for?

1. When the app is open, get data from cognito and sqlite.
2. Look for changes and sync.
3. Sync whenever something is saved in the database.